# Currency in different locale in groovy

Tags: groovy, locale, currency

I am writing code in groovy and want to display Currency name based on locale. For arabic locale, i would like to display different currencies of the world in arabic.

I have tried using java.util.Currency, but seems like it returns the Currency of the country of locale. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain what you need with an example? I assume it's more than `Currency.availableCurrencies​.each { println "$it.displayName $it.symbol" }`

Comment: Thanks tim for the reply. This would only display the name and symbol in english. I would like to display, suppose the Dirham currency in arabic .. درهم

Answer (score 0):

Does this get you what you want?

```
String currency = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance( new Locale( 'ar', 'MA' ) )
                              .decimalFormatSymbols
                              .currencySymbol
```

I get the value:

```
د.م.‏
```

Though (and I'm not sure if that's right)

Comment: Not exactly, it seems to return the currency symbol, i want to have Currency itself.